# Converting a list to coordinates

Tags: python, list, sage

My computer programming knowledge is very limited so bear with me if I don't use the jargons. I'm dealing with python and basically there are two functions A and C, of which I want to create another function B to convert output of A to a suitable input of C. Note here all the letters are integers.

```
Output of A: L=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],...] #finite list
L[0]=[a,b,c]
```

Now the problem is that input of C is in the form of (projective) coordinates.

```
Input of C: (x:y:z)
```

So I'm trying to create this bridge called function B between A and C with the following properties

```
Input of B:[x,a,b]
Output of B:(x/b:a/b:1)
```

So x/b and a/b here are rational numbers.

I don't know how much of this will help but I'm essentially trying to convert something I know from a database into something usable. At the moment this is what I've got that will give me the output of A.

```
D = CremonaDatabase()
x = EllipticCurve("389a1"); x
N = x.conductor(); N
y = str(N); y
z = len(y); z
a = x.cremona_label()[z:]; a
P = D.allgens(N)[a]; P
```

It seems like a very crude way of doing things. But it gets me where I want to so far.

I'd appreciate if somebody can tell me where to start looking.

Comment: I don't see any Python in your question. Show us some code.

Comment: `(x/b:a/b:1)` is not a Python data structure. Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code actual examples of input and output data. Also, review [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: With all due respect to @Tichodroma, this is a sort of add-on to Python called Sage, and certainly some of this is recognizably Python.  But the original poster probably could be more explicit about that.

Comment: To Haikal - it would be good, as the others say, to distinguish between your Sage code and mathematical terminology like (1:2:1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you pretty much answered your own question.
I'm not sure what X is or where it is defined, but im just going to assume it's taken care of

```
def b(input):
    return [[x/coord[1], coord[0]/coord[1], 1] for coord in input]
```

Comment: To clarify, this answer suggests you return a list `[x/b,a/b,1]` instead of something exactly like (x/b:a/b:1) as your question implies.

Comment: If it's just a simple conversion of the input values in the list into some other format, write a conversion function that does pretty much what is written here `def convert(in): return (x/in[1], in[0]/in[1], 1)` and use map() to apply it to all entries in A: `result = map(convert, A)`